# JQuery Validation plugin not working with minlength

Tags: validation, jquery-plugins

I've been fighting with this for a while now and have searched extensively to no avail. I grabbed a link someone posted here in response to my same question. [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jLnu/) I've copied the code to my editor, placed the stylesheet inline, linked all the scripts correctly I think...

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"</script>
<style> #docs{
display:block;
postion:fixed;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form_validation_reg_generate_user">
<input type="text" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('form#form_validation_reg_generate_user').validate({
    rules: {
        userPassword: {
            minlength: 5
        } 
    }, 
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submission'); // for demo
        return false; //form demo
    }
});

});
</script>
</body>
```

No validation occurs... I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious. It was working in a separate page when I was only validating required fields. Since adding the minlength... nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw3Cp/1/) with your code and it seems to work perfectly. Check if your `jquery.validate.min.js` path is correct and if you can access properly to every script from your system.

Also you can use your browser development tools to check if you have exceptions.

The `jquery.validate.iin.js` version I used in the text is from this [website](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Maybe you have an older script?

Comment: That was the answer! As soon as i put that one in place, I tested again and it worked as expected. Thanks!